# Use Recursion to Sum Digits until there is nothing left to sum

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

**Question**

Digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.

Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. This is only applicable to the natural numbers.

**My Code**

```js
function digital_root(n) {
    
      let a = n.toString();
      let ai = a.split('');
      
      let bi = ai.map((item)=>{
        return parseInt(item);
      })

      let newArr = [];

      for(let i = 0; i < bi.length; i++){
        let c = bi[i];
        newArr.push(c);
      }
      
      let d = newArr.reduce((total, item)=>{
      return total + item;
      }, 0); 
   
  function recursive(d){
    if(d < 10){
      return d
  }

      a = d.toString();
      ai = a.split('');
      
      bi = ai.map((item)=>{
        return parseInt(item);
      });

      newArr = [];

      for(let i = 0; i < bi.length; i++){
        let c = bi[i];
        newArr.push(c);
      }
      
      d = newArr.reduce((total, item)=>{
      return total + item;
      }, 0); 

      return recursive(d);
      }
     
     
    return d;
}


console.log(digital_root(123));
console.log(digital_root(111));
console.log(digital_root(51024));
```

**My Problem**

For some reason the code doesn't seem to recognise that I need to run the operation again if d >= 9.

How can I resolve the problem with the code that I have already done?

Also out of interest, how would you approach it, my answer seems quite convoluted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never call recursive function you made, replace `return d` to `return recursive(d);`

How I would do this:

```
function digital_root(n){
   return n < 10 ? n : digital_root(String(n).split('').reduce((acc,val) => acc+(val|0),0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am surprised that worked (because with my understanding the recursive function is within the "digital_root" function. Therefore when the recursive function returns, I wasn't expecting the "digital_root" function to return the result of the internal recursive function. Why does that work ? :)

Comment: @AndrewNeedsHelp: This is returning either `n` (if n < 10) or the results of that recursive call to `digital_root` (if n >= 10).  It's similar to `return  n % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'`.  The conditional expression `cond ? res : alt` yields either `res` or `alt`. At the end, the `return` statement simply returns the result of that conditional expression.

Answer (score 3):

Let's put in some comments to see what is going on.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
    // convert multiple digit number to String
    let a = n.toString();
    // split the String into an array of single digit Strings
    let ai = a.split('');
    // convert String array into int array  
    let bi = ai.map((item)=>{
        return parseInt(item);
    })
    
    // it looks like you are just copying the array here, 
    //I don't think there is a need for that
    //  let newArr = [];

    //  for(let i = 0; i < bi.length; i++){
    //    let c = bi[i];
    //    newArr.push(c);
    //  }
      
    // reduce the int array to the sum of its digits
    let d = bi.reduce((total, item)=>{
        return total + item;
    }, 0); 
   
    // That should be it, now just print it or recurse it
    if (d < 10) {
        return d;
    }
    // here is how you recurse, call the method from within the method
    return digital_root(d);

    // I'm not sure what you are doing here, you are repeating code
    // this is not how recursion works
//        function recursive(d){
//            if(d < 10){
//              return d
//            }

//            a = d.toString();
//            ai = a.split('');
      
//            bi = ai.map((item)=>{
//                return parseInt(item);
//            });

//            newArr = [];

//            for(let i = 0; i < bi.length; i++){
//                let c = bi[i];
//                newArr.push(c);
//            }
      
//            d = newArr.reduce((total, item)=>{
//                return total + item;
//            }, 0); 

//            return recursive(d);
//        }
//        return d;
}


console.log(digital_root(123));
console.log(digital_root(111));
console.log(digital_root(51024));
```

Comment: really useful, haha realised how trash my code was :'D in a good way!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Photon said, here's a simpler solution

```js
function sum(n) {
    if (n <= 9) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return sum((n % 10) + sum(n / 10));
    }
}

>>> sum(156)
... 3
>>> sum(9999)
... 9
>>> sum(10)
... 1
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have integer division, so you should use `Math.floor(n / 10)` instead. Also, `sum(x + sum(y)) === sum(x + y)`, so the last line should be `return sum(n % 10 + Math.floor(n / 10))`